How can I leave a comment on a pending suggested edit AFTER I rejected it?
I pressed "reject" on a suggested answer-edit, and then later realized that I should have given a reject comment explaining why the edit changed a valid answer for the question to an invalid one.
This is similar to How can I leave a comment on a pending suggested edit (before it's approved or rejected), so that the editor can see it? - but I have already pressed "reject", so I assume I cannot add a "Reject comment"
It is milder than How to change my suggested edit review as I don't want to fully change my decision, only comment on it.
I have tried to add a comment on the answer; How do I reverse a C++ vector?
Is there something more that I can/should do?

Nope, leaving a comment, and hoping the editor sees it is likely the best thing you can do. I, however, suspect that many editors don't read the rejection comments either, but maybe I'm just being cynical.

Admittedly, looking at your comment, that is actually probably the better place anyway; the edit your rejected clearly tries to change the answer and conflicts with the authors intent. If the code suggested worked, it probably should have been posted as an answer.

"Is there something more that I can/should do?" - Yes. Cup of tea, relax. You did more than most people would do.

Indeed, if you select "Reject & Edit", you have no chance within the review flow to leave a comment for the editor.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk You can link to the suggested edit in your edit summary and explain why you rejected it, though. I do so reasonably often, and always in cases where my changes are just a subset of the changes in the rejected edit (i.e. where I'm copying some of the proposed changes and rejecting others because they were harmful).

And how can I make an unrelated edit to a question, after I have rejected an edit (but it's still awaiting one more reject-vote.)

You have a few options, depending on the situation:

Leave an edit of your own with an appropriate summary (keeping in mind that anyone looking at the history will see the summary but may not see the rejected edit). For example, if you reject an edit because it did code formatting wrong, you can do it right.
Leave a regular comment. For example, if the edit was trying to clarify something but you rejected it because you think the editor might have misunderstood the post, you can ask OP to clarify with a comment. Or if there's a caveat to the answer (e.g., a specific function is incompatible, which the editor was suggesting), suggest they mention it. Note that if the editor's only interaction with the post was a pending/rejected edit, they can't be pinged, which is why I suggest focusing on the person who actually owns the post.
Do nothing. The other options are only appropriate for certain types of edits, and it's not often worthwhile to correct someone if it's a mistake that's not likely to be repeated.

